# Pyspark, EOFError - Memory issue or broken data?

Tags: pyspark, eoferror

I have a dataframe, which has about 2 million rows with URLs, 2 columns: id and url. I need to parse the domain from the url. I used lambda with urlparse or simple split. But I keep getting EOFError with both ways. If I create a random "sample" of 400 000, it works.

What is also interesting, is that pyspark shows me the top 20 rows with the new column domain, but I cannot do anything with it or I get the error again.

Is it a memory issue or is something wrong with the data? Can somebody please advise me or give me a hint?

I searched several questions regarding this, none of them helped me.

The code:

```
parse_domain = udf(lambda x: x.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0], 
returnType=StringType())
df = df.withColumn("domain", parse_domain(col("url")))
df.show()
```

Example urls:

```
"https://www.dataquest.io/blog/loading-data-into-postgres/"
"https://github.com/geekmoss/WrappyDatabase"
"https://www.google.cz/search?q=pyspark&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCZ786CZ786&oq=pyspark&aqs=chrome..69i64j69i60l3j35i39l2.3847j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
"https://search.seznam.cz/?q=google"
```

And the error I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 170, in manager
  File "/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 73, in worker
  File "/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 278, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/opt/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 692, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: There might be some corrupted rows in a csv. When exactly the error appears, `df.show()` works right?

Comment: @MikhailBerlinkov I get the error at df.show(), but the show gives me the first 20 rows as usual. What is the best way to find the corrupted row(s)? I was thinking of transferring it to pandas, do you have an idea how to do it with pyspark? Or any other better way...?

Comment: I think `pandas` would do with this amount of data. Another option would be to load the file as a text file in Spark and then check on corrupted rows.